# What is a good pattern for data marshaling between JS modules?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, design-patterns, architecture

This question is regarding a best practice for structuring data objects using JS Modules on the server for consumption by another module.

We have many modules for a web application, like login view, form handlers, that contain disparate fragments of data, like user state, application state, etc. which we need to be send to an analytics suite that requires a specific object format. Where should we map the data? (Pick things we want to send, rename keys, delete unwanted values.)

1. In each module. E.g.: Login knows about analytics and its formatting
   requirements.
2. In an analytics module. Now analytics has to know
   about each and every module's source format.
3. In separate [module]-analytics modules. Then we'll have dozen of files which don't have much context to debug and understand.

My team is split on what is the *right* design. I'm curious if there is some authoritative voice on the subject that can help us settle this.

Thanks in advance!

For example,

```
var objectForAnalytics = { 
  logged_in: user.get('isLoggedIn'), 
  app_context: application.get('environment') 
}; 
analytics.send(objectForAnalytics);
```

This short sample script uses functions from 3 modules. Where should it exist in a well-organized app?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS doesn't do marshaling, in the traditional sense.

Since the language encourages duck typing and runs all loaded modules in a single VM, each module can simply pass the data and let a consumer choose the fields that interest them.

Marshaling has two primary purposes, historically:

1. Delivering another module the data that it expects, since C-style structures and objects do not support extra data (usually).
2. Transferring data between two languages or modules built on two compilers, which may be using different memory layouts, calling conventions, or ABIs.

JavaScript solves the second problem using JSON, but the first is inherently solved with dictionary-style objects. Passing an object with 1000 keys is just as fast as an object with 2, so you can (and often are encouraged) to simply give the consumer what you have and allow them to decide what they need.

This is further reinforced in languages like Typescript, where the contract on a parameter type is simply a minimum set of requires. TS allows you to pass an object that exceeds those requires (by having other fields), instead only verifying that you are aware of what the consumer states they require in their contract and have met that.

When you do need to transform an object, perhaps because two library use the same data with different keys, creating a new object with shallow references is pretty easy:

```
let foo = {
  bar: old.baz,
  baz: old.bin
};
```

This does not change or copy the underlying data, so any changes to the original (or the copy) will propagate to the other. This does not include primitive values, which are immutable and so will not propagate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're totally right. I misappropriated the term "marshaling" to describe moving values around to get the format we needed. We are just dealing with plain JS objects. I edited the post so it make a bit more sense.

Comment: @Caqu I think your question is too broad for SO. You're asking where the bindings should exist, but that will sort itself out as you define your view/service/data exchange layers. The best answer I can give is that binding those modules together will typically happen at a fairly high level, often in the views or controller.

Comment: I see. I asked broadly because I have the same issue in a number of apps (Ember, Sails, and Backbone). I like your reasoning that "Passing an object with 1000 keys is just as fast as an object with 2, so you can (and often are encouraged) to simply give the consumer what you have and allow them to decide what they need." This points to our second option as the better structure for these tools.